# Django - permission denied for text file created on the fly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a downloadable text file on the fly, i think i have achieved this but when i run the code i get a permission denied error.

also when i open this text file, does it get created anywhere in the file system? as i dont want to store these files, just create them and have them downloaded to users machine

```
IOError at /networks/configs/STR-RTR-01/7
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'STR-CARD-RTR-01.txt'
```

config:

```
def configs(request, device, site_id):
    site = get_object_or_404(ShowroomConfigData, pk=site_id)   
    config_template  = get_object_or_404(ConfigTemplates, device_name=device)

    file_name = device[:4] + site.location.upper()[:4] + "-" + device[4:] + ".txt"

    device_config = None
    with open(file_name, 'w') as config_file:
        device_config = env.from_string(config_template.config)

        device_config.stream(
            STR         = site.location.upper()[:4],
            IP          = site.subnet,
            BGPASNO     = site.bgp_as,
            LOIP        = site.r1_loopback_ip,         
            Location    = site.location,
            Date        = site.opening_date,
        ).dump(config_file)

    return render(request, file_name, {
    })
```

Comment: What OS are you using, and what webserver?

Comment: Your Django process does not have the proper access permissions to that folder.

Comment: using Centos and apache, i dont know what folder they even go into, does the text file have to go into a folder? or will it not be saved after i close the file anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to provide a link where the user can download a file which is automatically generated, there's no need to write anything to disk.

You can just build the desired content in a Python string, and use the [`Content-Disposition`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) header to suggest that a user's browser should download the file rather than display it, and its `filename` parameter to specify a default filename for the user to save the file as.

A slightly simpler example of a view function which does this...

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_config_file(request):

    filename = 'config.txt'
    content = 'This is the content of my config file'
    content_type = 'text/plain'
    content_disposition = 'attachment; filename=%r' % filename

    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = content_disposition

    return response
```

Comment: @AlexW FWIW, it seems you can also treat an `HttpResponse` object as a file, so you should be able to do: `response = HttpResponse(content_type=content_type)` then `device_config.stream(...).dump(response)`